# Core data crashe with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When I try to save a new object into core data I am getting this error and a crash when I try to save the context:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have used the same method to save a newly created managed object in a number of other view controllers and all work fine except in this one. The issue started when I changed this line:

```
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
```

from .mainQueueConcurrencyType in the AppDelegate.

This is my persistent store coordinator setup in AppDel:

```
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: options)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

and this is the series of functions that lead up to the crash:

```
//get a new model for the components, same context, new FRC
    purchaseOrderModel = StockModel()
    purchaseOrderModel.setupManagedObjectContext()
    purchaseOrderModel.tableView = tableView

    if purchaseOrder == nil {
        //delegate?.editModeStateChange(editing: true)
        purchaseOrder = purchaseOrderModel.savePurchaseOrderWith("", supplier: nil, issueDate: Date(), deliveryDate: Date(), deliveryStatus: false)
        delegate?.newItemAdded()
        creatingNewPurchaseOrder = true
    }
```

calls to

```
 func savePurchaseOrderWith(_ poId: String?, supplier: NSManagedObject?, issueDate: Date, deliveryDate: Date, deliveryStatus: Bool? = nil) -> NSManagedObject {

    let newPurchaseOrder = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Purchase_Order", into: context)

    newPurchaseOrder.setValue(poId, forKey: "po_id")
    newPurchaseOrder.setValue(issueDate, forKey: "issue_date")
    newPurchaseOrder.setValue(deliveryDate, forKey: "est_delivery_date")
    newPurchaseOrder.setValue(supplier, forKey: "supplier")
    newPurchaseOrder.setValue(deliveryStatus, forKey: "delivered")

    _ = doSaveContext()

    return newPurchaseOrder
}
```

doSaveContext:

```
    func doSaveContext() -> Bool {
    do {
        try context.save() //editing POs makes it crash here after changing the created context in app delegate
        return true
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error saving context after delete \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return false
    }
}
```

and I get a SIGBART on `try context.save()`

It's been a couple of months since I worked on this project but this is what ground development to a halt so help would be great. What is weird is that every other path that creates a new empty object (say a delivery, new product etc) that ends in doSaveContext() works fine.

Happy to post extra information etc.

Update 1: When adding an exception break point it breaks in this function of my model class:

```
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type{
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.insert:
            //note that for insert we insert a row at _newIndexPath_
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete:
            //note that for delete we delete the row at _indexPath_
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [deleteIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.update:
            //note that for update we update the row at _indexPath_
            if indexPath != nil {
//                let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath)
//                let supplier = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(updateIndexPath)
//                cell!.textLabel?.text = supplier.name
            }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move:
            //note that for Move we delete the row at _indexPath_
            if let deleteIndexPath = indexPath {
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [deleteIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            }
            //note that for move we insert a row at _newIndexPath_
            if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            }
        }
    }
```

on the `self.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)` line if that helps. Can't find a clear log anywhere.

Update 2: Typing bt in the console when it breaks produces this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'NSManagedObjectContext 0x6040003cb8b0', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
    frame #0: 0x000000010c8e3b86 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw
    frame #1: 0x0000000106ee2068 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 343
    frame #2: 0x0000000107ff8362 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    frame #3: 0x0000000106986089 Foundation`-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    frame #4: 0x00000001096d9430 UIKit`-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 18124
    frame #5: 0x00000001096f5524 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:withUpdateAction:rowAnimation:usingPresentationValues:] + 1342
    frame #6: 0x00000001096f55f7 UIKit`-[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 118
  * frame #7: 0x00000001062013fd SC Dev`StockModel.controller(controller=0x00006000000efe00, anObject=Any @ 0x00007fff59ae7458, indexPath=nil, type=insert, newIndexPath=2 indices, self=0x0000600000478940) at StockModel.swift:283
    frame #8: 0x0000000106201f30 SC Dev`@objc StockModel.controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:) at StockModel.swift:0
    frame #9: 0x0000000107b6ef17 CoreData`__82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 5767
    frame #10: 0x0000000107a13bf8 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 168
    frame #11: 0x000000010cccb43c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #12: 0x000000010ccd2338 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 392
    frame #13: 0x0000000107a13afe CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 286
    frame #14: 0x0000000107b6d877 CoreData`-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 119
    frame #15: 0x0000000107f8f07c CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    frame #16: 0x0000000107f8ef7a CoreFoundation`_CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    frame #17: 0x0000000107f8ecc2 CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    frame #18: 0x0000000107f50a32 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    frame #19: 0x0000000107f4fbac CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 652
    frame #20: 0x00000001068c3842 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    frame #21: 0x00000001079fcbd5 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 773
    frame #22: 0x0000000107a9e0ca CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1658
    frame #23: 0x00000001079f6f0f CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2399
    frame #24: 0x00000001079fa7d3 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 419
    frame #25: 0x00000001062032fc SC Dev`StockModel.doSaveContext(self=0x0000600000673000) at StockModel.swift:381
    frame #26: 0x000000010620affd SC Dev`StockModel.savePurchaseOrderWith(poId="", supplier=nil, issueDate=2018-02-06 21:17:37 UTC, deliveryDate=2018-02-06 21:17:37 UTC, deliveryStatus=false, self=0x0000600000673000) at StockModel.swift:592
    frame #27: 0x000000010626ce76 SC Dev`PurchaseOrderDetailViewController.viewDidLoad(self=0x00007f941e038800) at PurchaseOrderDetailViewController.swift:68
    frame #28: 0x0000000106270f84 SC Dev`@objc PurchaseOrderDetailViewController.viewDidLoad() at PurchaseOrderDetailViewController.swift:0
    frame #29: 0x000000010975ad51 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
    frame #30: 0x00000001097a24dc UIKit`-[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
    frame #31: 0x00000001097a2818 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 153
    frame #32: 0x00000001097a392f UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 841
    frame #33: 0x00000001097a4b90 UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 115
    frame #34: 0x00000001099fb2ae UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    frame #35: 0x000000010968b551 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1331
    frame #36: 0x00000001093fb4ba QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    frame #37: 0x00000001093ff5a9 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 401
    frame #38: 0x00000001093881cd QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 365
    frame #39: 0x00000001093b3ae4 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
    frame #40: 0x00000001095e7687 UIKit`_afterCACommitHandler + 272
    frame #41: 0x0000000107f95db7 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    frame #42: 0x0000000107f95d0e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    frame #43: 0x0000000107f7a324 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    frame #44: 0x0000000107f79a89 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    frame #45: 0x000000010f6de9c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #46: 0x00000001095bcd30 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #47: 0x0000000106142607 SC Dev`main at AppDelegate.swift:18
    frame #48: 0x000000010cd47d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Update 3: wrapping the `_ = doSaveContext()` in `DispatchQueue.main.async {` gets me a few steps further along but still breaks on the same table insert line as before with the below log.

```
    bt
* thread #1, queue = 'NSManagedObjectContext 0x6000001da400', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010945bf11 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x000000010a572362 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    frame #2: 0x0000000108f00089 Foundation`-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    frame #3: 0x000000010b9e0430 UIKit`-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 18124
    frame #4: 0x000000010b9fc524 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:withUpdateAction:rowAnimation:usingPresentationValues:] + 1342
    frame #5: 0x000000010b9fc5f7 UIKit`-[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 118
  * frame #6: 0x000000010877a0cd SC Dev`StockModel.controller(controller=0x00006000000fea00, anObject=Any @ 0x00007fff575731c8, indexPath=nil, type=insert, newIndexPath=2 indices, self=0x000060400046aa00) at StockModel.swift:283
    frame #7: 0x000000010877ac00 SC Dev`@objc StockModel.controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:) at StockModel.swift:0
    frame #8: 0x000000010a0e8f17 CoreData`__82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 5767
    frame #9: 0x0000000109f8dbf8 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 168
    frame #10: 0x000000010f23843c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #11: 0x000000010f23f338 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 392
    frame #12: 0x0000000109f8dafe CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 286
    frame #13: 0x000000010a0e7877 CoreData`-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 119
    frame #14: 0x000000010a50907c CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    frame #15: 0x000000010a508f7a CoreFoundation`_CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    frame #16: 0x000000010a508cc2 CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    frame #17: 0x000000010a4caa32 CoreFoundation`-[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    frame #18: 0x000000010a4c9bac CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 652
    frame #19: 0x0000000108e3d842 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    frame #20: 0x0000000109f76bd5 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 773
    frame #21: 0x000000010a0180ca CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1658
    frame #22: 0x0000000109f70f0f CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2399
    frame #23: 0x0000000109f747d3 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 419
    frame #24: 0x000000010877bfcc SC Dev`StockModel.doSaveContext(self=0x000060000046fec0) at StockModel.swift:381
    frame #25: 0x0000000108783ebe SC Dev`closure #1 in StockModel.savePurchaseOrderWith(self=0x000060000046fec0) at StockModel.swift:593
    frame #26: 0x0000000108783f52 SC Dev`partial apply for closure #1 in StockModel.savePurchaseOrderWith(_:supplier:issueDate:deliveryDate:deliveryStatus:) at StockModel.swift:0
    frame #27: 0x00000001086c0b89 SC Dev`thunk for @callee_owned () -> () at AddProductViewController.swift:0
    frame #28: 0x000000010f2373f7 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #29: 0x000000010f23843c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #30: 0x000000010f2436f0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
    frame #31: 0x000000010a52fef9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #32: 0x000000010a4f4662 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2402
    frame #33: 0x000000010a4f3a89 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    frame #34: 0x0000000111c579c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #35: 0x000000010b8c3d30 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #36: 0x00000001086bb2d7 SC Dev`main at AppDelegate.swift:18
    frame #37: 0x000000010f2b4d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: You might want to add a breakpoint for all exceptions. Force a crash and post the log along with your question.

Comment: There's no message along with the exception?

Comment: @Adrian how do I find the log, i've added the exception break point.

Comment: @Josh Caswell Not that I can see, is there somewhere I might be missing it would show up?

Comment: It would show up in your console. If you stop on a breakpoint and don't stop the app, you can type `bt` at the `lldb` prompt and it'll tell you what methods were called just prior to the crash.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, have added that output to the question. Looks like it is a UI related issue. Could it be a problem where I am adding a new entity, the fetched results controller has detected that, tries to update the (now hidden) ui of the tableview but it can since the view controller that is trying to add a purchase order has some kind of lock on the core data context?

Comment: I see some UI stuff called just before it crashes. Before saving, perhaps you could call your save wrapped in this: `DispatchQueue.main.async {
      /* save here */
    }`.

Comment: Another thought would be to call the save from NSFetchedResultsController delegate method  `func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)`

Comment: @Adrian, I'm getting errors if i try to wrap the try/catch with that but changing the main call to ' DispatchQueue.main.async {
            _ = self.doSaveContext()
        }" gets it further along the process but still crashes eventually. The view controller to add details to the new purchase order now appear. will update question with logs

Comment: @Adrian, moving to that delegate method didn't help. Interestingly if I remove the save entirely it still breaks on `self.tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)` in `func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) `.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164657/discussion-between-adrian-and-simonbarker).

Comment: Are you calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on your table view anywhere?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes, in `controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)` I have a single line of code: `self.tableView.endUpdates()` - don't appear to be calling begin anywhere in the FRC delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to be certain but your stack traces strongly suggest that the problem is related to updating your table view from `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` callbacks. From one of your comments, the likeliest cause is that you're not calling `beginUpdates()` on the table view anywhere.

There are two basic approaches to updating a table view from `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. First, simple but not optimal: Don't implement `controllerWillChangeContent(_:)` or `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)`. *Do* implement `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)`, but use that method to `reloadData()` on your table view. Don't bother with begin/end updates or inserting/deleting/etc rows.

The second, better but slightly more complex, is to do **all** of these:

1. Implement `controllerWillChangeContent(_:)` and use it to call `beginUpdates()`.
2. Implement `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` to insert/update/etc rows in the table.
3. Implement `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` and use it to call `endUpdates()`.

The "begin" and "end" calls are both crucial. I can't be 100% sure that this is what's causing your specific crash, but I'd expect leaving out `beginUpdates()` to cause some kind of crash.

Comment: Great, I think I am using a mixed method of both of those approaches thinking back over the decisions I have made - will take a look tomorrow when I can get back in front of the code again.

Comment: Looks like this was the problem, only just got back to working on this so thanks @Tom